# Limit string length in vue material chips

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-material

I'm using [Vue Material Chips component](https://vuematerial.io/components/chips/) to collect some string arrays, and I have to limit the length of each string (let's say, 30 characters).

They have the `md-limit` prop, it limits the number of strings I can have in my array but not the number of chars I can have on each string.

I do believe I'll have to build a custom validation before adding each string to the array (I've tried to use `v-validate` but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the chips component).

If anybody had a suggestion how could I achieve it, it would be very appreciated! Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I got this right

1. You have an array with your chips inside (ex:
   `this.fruits = ['Banana','Apple','Pineapple','SomeOtherFruitWithMoreThan30Chars']`)
2. When you hit enter, the v-model variable gets updated and pushes your input into that array

What I would do:

1. Make a deep watch (maybe normal works fine)

```js
watch: {
  fruits:{
    // newVal is the new value of the array
    handler: function(newVal) {

      //checks if the last element of the array has more than 30 chars
      if(newVal[(newVal.length - 1)].length > 30){
        //remove the last element of the array
        this.fruits.pop()
      }
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

2. Try to use the formatter function of the component as a validation check
   **md-format** and return null if more than 30 chars

Comment: tnx, it already helped me a lot! I probably will need to send an error message to the chips field, but for the problem I exposed here your answer is great =]